Trigger event when meeting transcription ends
I'm building a cloud-based application and need to trigger an event or webhook when a Google Meet meeting ends and its transcription is completed. The webhook should send the following details:
Meeting transcript
List of participants (names, roles, join/leave times)
Meeting metadata (ID, duration, etc.)
(Optionally) Audio/Video recording links
How can I set this up to automatically trigger the webhook when transcription is finished in Google Meet? I’m looking for guidance on detecting transcription completion and sending this data via webhook.
Is there any push notifcation or any webhook or any script google provides else I have to run a cron job at regular intervals .

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
